# Labels of arrows in a tikzcd diagram not showing in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams, labels, tikz-cd

I just made a diagram for a Beamer presentation, but the names of the arrows involved do not appear after compiling. Here's a picture reflecting the situation.

[image]

Here's some minimal working example (actually, I include all the packages are part of the document)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Índice}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
El núcleo de $\mu$ es la intersección de los núcleos de $\mu'$ y $\mu''$.\pause Por la hipótesis de inducción, existe un entorno $V\subset U$ en el que existe una sizigia $\lambda'$ para $\mu'$ y una sizigia $\mu''\circ\lambda'$.
    $$
    \begin{tikzcd}
        _n\mathscr O^r\arrow[r,"\lambda''"]&_n\mathscr O^s\arrow[drr,"\mu''\circ\lambda'"]\arrow[r,"\lambda'"]&_n\mathscr O^p\arrow[dr,"\mu''"]\arrow[r,"\mu'"]&_n\mathscr O^{q-1}\\
        &&&_n\mathscr O
    \end{tikzcd}
    $$
\pause
Es evidente que $\lambda=\lambda'\circ\lambda'': _n\mathscr O^r\rightarrow _n\mathscr O^p$ es la sizigia de $\mu$ que buscamos, concluyéndose así la demostración.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest to use `\[...\]` instead of `$$ ... $$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` into your preamble and you can see the labels. I think that the problem it is the babel not recognize by `tikz-cd` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Índice}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
El núcleo de $\mu$ es la intersección de los núcleos de $\mu'$ y $\mu''$.\pause Por la hipótesis de inducción, existe un entorno $V\subset U$ en el que existe una sizigia $\lambda'$ para $\mu'$ y una sizigia $\mu''\circ\lambda'$.
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
       {}_n\mathscr{O}^r\arrow[r,"\lambda''"]&{}_n\mathscr{O}\arrow[drr,"\mu''\circ\lambda'"]\arrow[r,"\lambda'"]&{}_n\mathscr{O}^p\arrow[dr,"\mu''"]\arrow[r,"\mu'"]&{}_n\mathscr{O}^{q-1}\\
        &&&{}_n\mathscr{O}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\pause
Es evidente que $\lambda=\lambda'\circ\lambda'': {}_n\mathscr{O}^r\rightarrow{}_n\mathscr{O}^p$ es la sizigia de $\mu$ que buscamos, concluyéndose así la demostración.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]